# How to redirect to main page when user re-login using Apache Shiro and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, shiro

I am new to Apache Shiro and JSP. Right now, I am able to login using Shiro. However, if a user is logged in and the user key in the login page on URL directly like `localhost/testing/login.jsp`, the system will redirect the user to the login page, so the user continue to key in username and password then the user will stuck there forever eventhough the username and password is correct. In my `shiro.ini`, I put `authc.successUrl  = /index.jsp`, it is working for the first login but if the scenerio that I just mentioned and it is not going to redirect.

Here is the login form

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html> 
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="login">
<form name="loginform" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe">
        <label for="rememberMe">rememberMe</label>
    </div>
    </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my partial `shiro.ini` file,

```
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.failureKeyAttribute=loginFailure
authc.successUrl  = /index.jsp

# name of request parameter with username; if not present filter assumes 'username'
authc.usernameParam = user
# name of request parameter with password; if not present filter assumes 'password'
authc.passwordParam = pass
# does the user wish to be remembered?; if not present filter assumes 'rememberMe'
authc.rememberMeParam = remember
```

Comment: What redirects is your browser going through? is it ever going to `/index.jsp`?

Comment: Hi sorry for the very late reply. Actually it does redirect to `/index.jsp` , just that what if the user manually enter the `/login.jsp` directly into the URL and enter the password and username again eventhought they are already logged in before they enter to this `/login.jsp` webpage. My question is, is there anyway to detect the user is already logged in and prevent user to go into login page again.

Comment: In that case, does the user get redirected to the `/index.jsp`? If so is there something on that page that is blocking access?  Do you have the ShiroFilter in place for all routes?

Comment: Nope, the user still in `/login.jsp` . So far I did not set up anything about blocking access. I didnt set up any ShiroFilter but I have the basic ShiroFilter with all those include and forwards. I think need to find a way to detect current user session. If th system detected the user has logged in then redirect to index page else approch user to login. Right now, I am thinking of using Servlet to check the user session. But is there other ways to detect without using Servlet ?

Comment: Can you put together an example app and stick it on GitHub that can reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put

```
<shiro:authenticated>
<c:redirect url="index.jsp"/>
</shiro:authenticated>
```

in your login page first few lines of html

Comment: Hi, your method is working but i found another way to solve it but using servlet to check current user session.  For future reference, if using your method then we need to add these 2 libraries  `<%@ taglib prefix="shiro" uri="http://shiro.apache.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>` . Btw, thank you for providing another method.

Comment: these are not libraries these are just JSTL tags.